# How to select a cell based on the current month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, accounting

I'm looking for some excel help.
I am trying to make a total cell that changes the value selected based on what month it currently is. Basically in the image the left cell indicates the $ amount for that month and that $ amount is in the cells on the right.

For example I want the total cell (not shown in the screenshot) to show 15363.21 from March 1 to 31st, and then change to 15388.81 on April 1st.

I have done some research but can't get this to work for me.

[image: My sheet]

[Pretending month is march](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVaB8.png) [Pretending month is April](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57mVB.png)

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS()` function.

Comment: Use match() to get the entries for the current month which you can pick up using today(). Several examples exist on here.

Comment: Could you show us your expected output. i.e. how you want to achieve it like by creating it manually

Comment: I'll upload the example Mayukh

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking for a lookup: "find the single cell in Column A that contains the current month and year, then return the corresponding single cell in Column F."

There are several ways to do this, but assuming your Excel version supports XLOOKUP, the code to place inside your total cell could be:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(MONTH($A$4:$A$11)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(YEAR($A$4:$A$11)=YEAR(TODAY())),$F$4:$F$11)
```